# How to skip a line when using Beautifulsoup find_all?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall, skip

This is my code. It finds all car links without "https://" and domain name. However one of them is a full link with "https://...".
How to write a code, which will skip this one result, to tell him don't mind the line with "https://" or any other text?

```
for page_number in range(1, 10):
    url = f"xyz{page_number}"
    page_number += 1
    req = requests.get(url)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    get_car_links = soup.find_all(class_="info-container")
    for i in get_car_links:
        car_links = i.find("a", class_="title")
        car_datas = (car_links.get("href"))
        print(car_datas)
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing *page_number* ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add an `if` condition to check and skip the case.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for page_number in range(1, 10):
    url = f"xyz{page_number}"
    page_number += 1
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    
    get_car_links = soup.find_all(class_="info-container")
    for i in get_car_links:
        if  not 'http' in i.find('a', class_='title').get('href'):
            car_links = i.find("a", class_="title")
            car_datas = car_links.get("href")
            print(car_datas)
```

Comment: You could use str.startswith() rather than *in* to avoid possible ambiguities. Even better, use urllib.parse.urlsplit() or urllib.parse.urlparse() to determine if the URL has a scheme

Comment: The edited version worked. Thank you

Comment: Sorry @Alberi, I missed finding the `a` tag first. I have updated the code.

Comment: Right @DarkKnight, using `urllib` will be the best way.

Comment: @Zero It is working now, after you edited your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @DarkKnight I am not familiar with it yet.

Comment: No worries @Alberi, and if you're certain that all requests go with `https`, you can update the string in if statement to `https://` for better matches.

Comment: @Zero /foo/http/bar is a valid URI. It does not have a scheme. Your code will find 'http' in the string and assume that it's a scheme specification which would be wrong

Comment: Yeah @DarkKnight, I used a basic if for simplicity, and OP isn't aware of `urllib`, so we can leave it for now. OP can update if string to `https://` though, if he's certain that all requests go through `https`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is eliminate (ignore) HREFs that have a scheme - e.g., https, http, ftp, mailto

Therefore it seems sensible to use a URL parser rather than searching for constant strings.

Something like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

URL = 'https://example.com/bar'

def main():
    for page in range(1, 10):
        with requests.get(f'{URL}{page}') as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
            for car_link in soup.find_all(class_='info-container'):
                if (a := car_link.find('a', class_='title')):
                    if not urlparse(href := a['href']).scheme:
                        print(href)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```